# How to solve C'=-a*N'?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am a Molecular Biologist and I had been watching this [video](https://youtu.be/Y3d7zTd1fAw?list=PLqOZ6FD_RQ7lnGZ7fkn503y_7U4rrJ-Se) on Bacterial growth. At 9:25, the teacher solves differential equation by integrating:
$$
C'= -\alpha*N'
$$
Integrating both sides of the equation using t (I guess)
$$
\int C'= \int-\alpha*N'
$$
The answer, I am having is
$$
C=-\alpha*Nt +Cz
$$
while the true answer was
$$
C=-\alpha*N + Cz
$$

So I request you to please tell me, how to get the same answer as the instructor has gotten.
Best Regards

Comment: I guess $N$ is a function and $N'$ is its derivative, and if you integrate the derivative $N'$ you get the function $N$ (plus a constant).

Comment: oh yes true... let me make it right... thank you

Comment: I think you missed my point. You are treating $N$ as a constant, but it is really a function, as is $C$. I.e. $C = C(t)$ and $N = N(t)$ and the equation to integrate is $C'(t) = - \alpha N'(t)$.

Comment: Ok let me see it again...